# JMeter's Counter without required fields

Tags: jmeter

I notice that [Counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) can remain without any required fields:

`Reference name` - can be empty will create a JMeter variable with empty string which can be called as `${}`

`Starting value` - can be empty will create a value from `0`

`Increment` - can be empty will increment a value with `0` (no increment)

Is it a JMeter bug or an hidden feature or just a documentation bug? I notice that [Counter doc](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62320) had changed in next version, but it doesn't reflect this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You opened a bug for this:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62446

I guess you should provide a patch for documentation as for now Jmeter never forces in gui any value even if mandatory.

This would be the ideal solution but would need a common piece if code in GUI fields.